# Create a symmetric matrix in R

Tags: r

How can I create this matrix in R? Actually for example the fisrt element of matrix `A[1,1]` is equal to sum of multiplication of `x^2` and `j`, `A[1,2]` is equla to sum of multiplication of `x`and `y`and `j`, ...

```
          x = 1:3
          y = c(2, 4, 6)
          z = c(3, 7, 9)
          j = c(5, 10, 15)
         > A
            [,1] [,2] [,3]
       [1,]  180  360  560
       [2,]  360  720 1120
       [3,]  560 1120 1750
```

Comment: what have y and z got to do with this? We shouldn't need to solve that puzzle.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My guess:

```
R > mat = as.matrix(cbind(x, y,z))
R > mat
     x y z
[1,] 1 2 3
[2,] 2 4 7
[3,] 3 6 9
R > t(mat)%*%diag(j)%*%mat
    x    y    z
x 180  360  560
y 360  720 1120
z 560 1120 1750
```